# lookup field test if value is (none) from SPD Workflow

Tags: workflow, lookup-column

everything is in the title.

I have a lookup field set to optional and I need from my Workflow to test this field.

When you do not select any value, you have (none) in the interface but I cannot seem to be able to test it in the workflow

I have tried is empty but it does not work.

Comment: Strange. I just tested it with `Is CurrentItem:LookUp is empty` and it works (LookUp is name of my lookup field)

Comment: indeed the is empty works, I retest it again and it worked. Publishing issue I Guess thx anyway

Comment: Good. I posted my comment as answer so you can mark it as answer if you think it was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If the lookup allows multiple values you can check if it is equal to `{"results":null}`, which is the JSON string that will be returned when the field is empty (for SharePoint 2013 at least).

Comment: +1 This works once the `Current Item:lookup` field is converted into string and then compared to `{"results":null}`.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested it with `Is CurrentItem:LookUp is empty` and it works.

Note: `LookUp` is name of my test lookup field

Comment: No, I face same problem, Is CurrentItem:Lookup is empty does not work with me too!!!

Comment: Same here, I don't seem to get a consistent behavior with CurrentItem:Lookup is empty

Answer (score 1):

In SPD 2010 workflow to verify the lookup value is select or not using the following condition

**Is CurrentItem:LookUp equals 0**

Answer (score 0):

The string value of a an empty lookup column is actualy "0;#". You need to test if the column is equal to this value.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the lookup field (*City Lookup*) is returning the **Title** of the item in the second list.

Steps to test for emptiness:

1. Set a variable of type String to the Lookup Field
2. Test the variable for emptiness like usual:

[image: Test lookup field for emptiness]

This is in a SPD2013 Workflow on SharePoint 2016.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (SP Workflow 2013 engine), the lookup column provided only the option for comparing "equal to" and "not equal to", so there was no "is empty".

What I did was simply assign the lookup value to a workflow string variable and then check the workflow value for empty. There, the option was available.